# Ionic 3 nested ion-split-pane using ion-nav with a ion-menu wont switch and behaves unexpectedly (Deeplinks)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, navigation, deep-linking, ion-menu

I have a nav `split-pane` with switchable nested `split-pane` pages with an info side menu that is setup like so:

```
       split-pane
  menu           ion-nav
================================
                 split-pane 
           ion-nav    menu
       =========================
|     |[            |          ]
| NAV |[   CONTENT  | SIDE MENU] <- bugged
|     |[            |          ]
```

The goal is to only show the side menu when needed and still have a large content container.

The problem is when using the main navigation on the left to `setRoot` (much like tabs), the content will only switch every 2nd navigation switch and the side menu typically disappears on the first switch then incorrectly shows the previous page's side menu.

I've done some logging with `getActiveNavs()` and `getRootNavs()` and found that many navigations are being created `n4`, `n5`, `n6`, `n7` etc and sometimes `activeNav` and `rootNav` are different.

Comment: Can you share your template code?